# spring-security-oauth2-provider provider on Grails

Tags: grails, oauth-2.0

I need to expose a specific URL of my Grails web-application. However, I want it to be protected by a OAuth2 client-credentials flow(grant_type).
To be precise, a external agent will send a request to something like

```
http://server-url/oauth/token?client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&grant_type=client_credentials
```

and obtain a access_token. Then, my URL(protected resource) should be accesible with something like

```
http://server-url/resource?access_token={access-token obtained before}
```

My approach till now involved using this grails plugin ( spring-security-oauth2-provider: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider ).

Following the documentation given at https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider, I have been able to setup the granting access_token part (A registered client is able to get the access token by providing its id and secret. But, I am not able to understand from the tutorial as to how to protect a given resource ( restrict access to clients with the access token only ).

The documentation link above only mentions upto the stage of setting up of access token distribution and then moves to user approval ( which I don't require ).

Any pointers regarding as to how to proceed will be nice. Alternatively, suggestions regarding any other options for fulfilling the requirements are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grails plugin is a wrap of spring security plugin [spring-security-oauth](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth), take a look to spring-security-oauth documentation. I assume you already have familiarity with ouath2 specifications, if not read [enter link description here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-27) and even [google oauth2 API](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) is a google documentation sample.
The plugin you are using is not updated to the last release of spring-security-oauth, if you want take a look I have forked and updated it on [github](https://github.com/ftaiolivista/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider)

Comment: Thanks. I had looked into the spring-security-plugin before, but then I found this. Correct me, if I am wrong, but I guess I should look into sparklr use-cse for my requirements.

Comment: Hey, I looked into the spring security plugin docs. But, I am still not able to figure out what to do for my use-case. The oauth2-provider plugin that I mentioned is already creating the access_token. However, I don't know how and/or where to access it and tell grails or the spring-security plugin to protect ( let's say a controller using it.

Comment: Yes sparklr sample is the master source of info on how configure oauth2. Take a look to this two files https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml They defines all the filters and beans needed to protect a resource like a controller. In the spark the filter that protect resources is resourceServerFilter

Answer (score 0):

You can protect your resource by using the spring-security-core. Example: you can list the url path in Requestmap.

```
new Requestmap(url: '/api/v1/states/**', configAttribute: 'ROLE_USER,ROLE_USER').save()
new Requestmap(url: '/api/v1/subscriptions/**', configAttribute: 'ROLE_USER,ROLE_USER').save()
new Requestmap(url: '/api/v1/surveys/**', configAttribute: 'ROLE_USER,ROLE_USER').save()
```

I have tested with grails plugin "spring-security-oauth2-provider:1.0.0.M5.1".